# Requesting "CI/CD Satisfaction" question on 2019 developer survey

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

I'm curious how the developer community finds their Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery experience, and how their tooling contributes to that.

I've tried Jenkins, Circle, and Travis. Jenkins costs more than it benefits in my experience, while Circle and Travis benefit more than they cost (although I still expect to spend an hour or two on maintaining them monthly.)

I've heard about Concourse and Drone but haven't used them myself.

I imagine there's other solutions I've never heard of.

Comment: This would be useful with the language/framework you use. Some CI are known for being more powerful if used with a specific language in mind.

Comment: What are Jenkins, Circle, Travis, Concourse, Drone, CI, and CD?

Comment: And the non-comedy explanation?

Comment: [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and [Continuous Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery). CI is usually as simple as having some automated process build your app on every commit to source control. CD is automating the delivery of the built code to one or more environments (e.g. UAT or Production)

Comment: "I'm curious how the developer community finds their CI/CD experience and how their tooling contributes to that." Just ask that on SO. Should be on topic if worded appropriately.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think it would, since it's ultimately asking for opinions.

Comment: @cybermonkey Many questions in the surveys do not ask for opinions, it's more like "What do you use?" but with more statistical power. One could probably ask a few "What CI/CD services exist?" "Which CI/CD services can do a particular task?" questions without getting into opinions. Or is this question here just asking for which CI/CD systems are most popular right now?

Comment: @Trilarion See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and you will find pretty much exactly your wording as don'ts. The point is - SO question should have a "right" answer. Unless the project you want to set up CI/CD for is well-known, the "best tool" cannot be determined, because as it always is, each tool has different usecases it is ideal for, typically as a result from the trade-off "convention" vs. "configuration".

Comment: @LWChris I'm a bit confused. I didn't really ask for the best in the two examples. But I wonder now if the asker here only wants to know what are popular CI/CD services or what exactly he would be interested to know? Actually, I think now that my problem is that it doesn't seem clear from this question which question exactly should be part of the developer survey, at least to me. The suggestion was, that maybe some of the questions that the asker wants to know can already be solved by directly asking on SO.

Comment: @Trilarion what cybermonkey and LWChris are trying to explain to you is that your suggestion to "just ask that on SO" is wrong.

Comment: @Stijn Yes, got that.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks. I guess "Build & Publish" in Visual Studio is like Manual Integration, then?

Comment: @Trilarion My wording would be `Rank your experience with the following Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery platforms. (Never used / Used and dissatisfied / Used and ambivalent / Used and satisfied)`

Comment: The "Loved/Dreaded/Wanted" division like they did for some technologies last year would also do. I just requested the same for version control systems: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378565/207791