# Developer Survey 2019: Any Topic Suggestions?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

I’m Anita, a Product Manager here at Stack Overflow.

October’s nearly over, and it’s beginning to look a lot like survey season. That’s right, we’re planning the Developer Survey 2019!

Thanks to you, we had some great questions in the 2018 survey, such as:

- [“What time do you typically wake up in the morning?”](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-what-time-do-developers-wake-up)
- [“How much time do you spend on a computer each day?”](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-how-much-time-do-developers-spend-on-a-computer)
- [“How much time do developers spend outside?”](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-how-much-time-do-developers-spend-outside)
- [“How often do developers skip meals to be productive? How often do developers exercise?”](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-healthy-habits)
- [“What do developers use to stay comfortable while working?”](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#work-what-do-developers-use-to-stay-comfortable-while-working)

(Check out the [results from the 2018 survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018) if you haven’t already.)

We also received excellent suggestions about topics we *didn’t* get to use, such as:

- [Imposter syndrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358084/9893889)
- [Screen size, aspect ratio, and orientation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319267/9893889)
- [Team size](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358012/9893889) (in addition to - but separate from - your company size)
- [Better acknowledgement of freelancers / part-timers / hobbyists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357936/developer-survey-2018-any-topic-suggestions#comment523420_357936) - the “I’m not a full-time developer” folks (who belong here, too!)

These are still being considered for the 2019 survey. Each year is a delicate balance between including your suggested topics and keeping the survey reasonably sized.

So - what’s new for you this year? What would you like to see asked in the 2019 survey? While we can’t promise to include all suggestions, we will read and consider each and every one.

As always, thanks for your time and contributions! **Please add your suggestions by Friday, Nov. 2.**

Comment: I think that it's awesome that you ask the community what they want for the survey - but please consider asking fewer questions than last year. It took me 30 minutes to complete last years survey (as compared to previous years where it took 5-10 minutes)

Comment: @Daniel It was the exact opposite from my experience. I personally like to give detailed answers to a survey and 5 - 10 minutes is way to short to give enough meaningful data considering the details in evaluations we get in the survey results.

Comment: But cutting of the people who do not want to take part on such a long survey, doesn't help in meaningful data either. @Filnor Imo 30 minutes is still optimistic for non native speakers.

Comment: I would like to see a graph for Salary and Experience by Region / Location

Comment: I already suggested a question in a separate post a long time ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370726/ideology-question-suggestion-for-developer-survey-2019. Was it considered?

Comment: We can ask another question like "Do you work on side-projects (start-up ideas)  when you already have a full-time job? "

Comment: Another interesting question will be "Do you practice coding questions when you are trying to change job  and attending an interview ? or do you just just go and give the interview with-out preparing because you are already working on it at a day job?"

Comment: Should this question be closed since we're past the Friday deadline?

Comment: @BSMP that, or locked as "answers are a community effort".

Comment: Why is the question closed? It just invites to ask [seperate questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377068/can-we-have-a-question-into-the-next-developer-survey-regarding-unit-testing).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: …. because it is past **Friday, Nov. 2**? (Boldness *sic* the original post; see the bottom line.) Unless you want to believe it's due for November 2019? It does not look as if you can keep adding topic suggestions right until the survey starts.

Comment: Why close? I find the links interesting and information is very helpful. Closing would be hiding and destruction of invested information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should have been closed long time back. But still accepting answers.

Answer (score 217):

> How many hours do you work per week?

Combine this answer with salary reports for better **insights into how much each position's time is worth**.

A $137,000/yr Engineering Manager position may look rosy from the perspective of a $100,000/yr Full-Stack Developer, but if you couple those salary reports with 60 hrs/wk and 40 hrs/wk, respectively, it paints a different picture.

Comment: I'd also like to see this broken down further: how much do you work at your "day" job, how much do you work for "extra" projects at work, how much do you work on personal projects in your spare time?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I don't understand the distinction between "extra" projects at work and your "day" job. If you are working on something at your job, that's your job; there is no "extra". I think almost all job descriptions in modern office environments include the rider "and other duties as assigned"; while it's true I would not be reasonably expected to replace light bulbs or interact with customers as a programmer at my job, any programming related tasks I might work on would 100% be considered "doing my job".

Comment: @TylerH I'm talking about stuff like volunteer opportunities, "20%" projects, hackathons, side projects, etc. Stuff that doesn't really count towards your "real job" but isn't something you're doing completely on personal time either.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Such things don't exist at most companies, I wager. Most companies are quite different from Google.

Comment: @TylerH Sure, I don't disagree with that. I'd still be interested in the split, as many people have side projects regardless of where they work.

Comment: Also combine this with gender. http://freakonomics.com/podcast/what-can-uber-teach-us-about-the-gender-pay-gap/

Comment: @Chloe if we learned from past surveys, they would ask about gender and other self-identifying questions.

Comment: Building on top of what @KevinWorkman said , I'd would like to see how many hours you need to work to do what your managers ask you to do vs the actual hours you bill them.

Answer (score 133):

> At what age did you write your first program? E.g. Hello World, Scratch project, etc.

Comment: Second - I feel this will have strong correlation with some other interesting metrics.

Comment: Good question, but I think clarification is needed on what constitutes learning to program. In my case there was a long gap between being able to write a simple loop/hello world in QBASIC, and being able to write a useful application in C#.

Comment: @AndyJ Maybe a two-part question would help provide that clarification? E.g. "At what age did you complete your first programming project? What was it?" With a list of options: website, embedded system, video game, utility script, etc.

Comment: A bit unfair question for non-milleniums (me including). There were little to no computers in the world until ~1990 when I was already 10. My nephew plays game from 1.5. And then what is exactly first program? Hello world is enough? Should it be compiled? Is modifying someone js script (or even html page) counts?

Comment: @JakeReece A video game would be an impressive first project :) Where is the hello world option? haha

Comment: @chevybow actually a lot of kids make video games as a first project. Usually either only "games" by some stretch of the word, or crappy snowclones of some game they like, but yeah.

Comment: @AndyJ I've updated the question.

Comment: @Sinatr [IBM PCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer#Debut) first came out in 1981. And they weren't the first home/office computers. ["Home Computers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_computer) were available from 1977. In the UK many schools would have had [BBC Computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Micro#History) by the time you started school. When analyzing the results of the surveys the results are often grouped by geographical location, to account for things like availability of hardware.

Comment: Do [punch cards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KG2M4ttzBnY) count?

Comment: @ahiijny yes, definitely. They're programs like any other.

Comment: Answer: 3......

Answer (score 119):

Does your company regularly employ unit tests in the development of their products?

*(I'm interested in this one because I know a lot of devs whose doesn't)*

Comment: Maybe with options: Yes, it's required / Yes because the developers do it on their own / No

Comment: yeah. everyone in the whole industry pretend like they care but never allot user-story points to it. And they don't really get mad at you when it's not done either because they obviously know it would be ridiculous given they themselves never allow time for it. As a front-end dev testing is particularly ignored and I've started to just get used to it, but maybe I shouldn't be?

Comment: Over the whole range of programming - from web GUIs to embedded real-time systems - how, when and why you test becomes very domain-specific. So I don't find this particularly interesting, as there is nothing to be learned. Should I answer "Yeah I always design tests on dedicated pins for my real-time requirements, form a PWM corresponding to each tasks' individual time and measure them with an oscilloscope".  After which the web guys go "huh, wut...?" And they are likely as little interested in knowing this, as I am in knowing how they test their web stuff.

Comment: @Lundin eh, automated tests are pretty universally applicable. At least I know a lot of devs who don't have the time budget to reliably do these, so I'd like to know how prevalent that is

Comment: @Magisch Automated tests in embedded typically means designing a test interface out from the board, and/or a special test firmware in place of the production firmware and/or a test rig where the PCB can be mounted and connected to probes. What part of it is universally applicable?

Comment: @Lundin by mostly universally applicable I meant in non embedded programming, which is most programming. Sure there are different frameworks and systems for automating tests, but on a fundamental level, doing or not doing automated tests is a important distinction, imo

Comment: Not sure how I would answer this question if it appeared on a survey. Internal teams at my company (like mine) don't unit test. Client facing ones do. I guess technically that means my company employs unit testing but its not as if every developer is writing tests for all their code

Comment: I like to phrase this question, "What testing framework do you use?" The only wrong answer is "None."

Comment: Interesting question, only because I would have to first look up what unit testing is before I can be sure my answer is "no".

Comment: @Lundin I don't get how the exact implementation of automated/unit testing matters. The question is yes/no, are you doing them or not. Sure, there's going to be some trends with industry, but there's still plenty of embedded unit testing frameworks...

Comment: I think a very interesting follow-up question would be *If no, why?* with options such as *No time budgeted for it*, *Boss does not believe it is needed*, *Developers do not believe it is needed* or something like that.

Answer (score 110):

In addition to the **[impostor syndrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357936/developer-survey-2018-any-topic-suggestions/358084#358084)** question you mentioned in your question, I'd like to see some questions about **[Stack Overflow's reputation of being unfriendly](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).**

Some examples might include:

- Do you see Stack Overflow [as a wiki](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)?
- Have you ever felt unwelcomed by Stack Overflow?
- Should Stack Overflow do more to welcome novices?

A <s>couple</s> few suggestions from the comments:

- Do you see any improvements after the welcome-wagon measures?
- Do you feel the "Welcoming" initiative improves the experience of more experienced users?
- Does Stack Overflow do enough to welcome novices, too little or too much?
- I feel welcome on Stack Overflow (with a likert scale)
- Has the welcoming initiative improved your experience?
- Has the welcoming initiative worsened your experience?

I'm not great at coming up with the specific questions, but the idea is that we should take the temperature of the conversation happening now. It would be interesting to compare answers to these questions along account age, reputation, or other factors.

Comment: Addition: Do you see any improvements after the welcome-wagon measures?

Comment: yes! great one! Stack can't pretend it's system isn't directly the cause for this behavior. And of course they didn't mean for it to be this way but it just takes a tiny bit of thinking and you can forecast that this was the only logical emergent behavior these set of mechanics and rules could bear. In my mind the points system lean heavily on rank and power, authority. Also edits and duplicate weeding. Through this, you lower the time spent on an interaction you lower it's quality. people don't read, jump to conclusions and voila! a false duplicate flag. downvotes are also a bad idea.

Comment: _"Do you feel the "Welcoming" initiative improves the experience of more experienced users?"_ I often feel like the regulars are completely ignored in favor of being "welcoming".

Comment: The same questions about Open Source: Open Source has exactly the same problems that Stack Overflow has (for the same reasons.. ).

Comment: I think this question should be asked more neutrally. E.g. "Does Stack Overflow do enough to welcome novices, too little or too much?"

Comment: @S.L.Barth there's no way you can ask about people sentiment without sounding bad or biased ("novices" to what? SO, programming, life?)

Comment: @Braiam Maybe, but we should at least strive for the most neutral wording. Especially when the issue is so sensitive as the Welcoming initiative.

Comment: @AmitJoshi I've added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @tatsu Thanks for the feedback. I don't want to turn this into a debate about the welcoming initiatives though, so I encourage you to comment on one of the threads discussing it.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I've added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Your welcoming question will be more in line with survey best practices if it is worded positively: "I feel welcome on Stack Overflow" (with a likert scale). Also, it is better to ask respondents about themselves, rather than about someone else (has the welcoming initiative improved your experience, rather than "is it good for novices, is it good for experienced users")

Comment: @DeNovo Good feedback, thanks. I've added your suggestions.

Comment: @DeNovo was about to recommend that, but including the "I don't know/care" option.

Comment: To be clear, re: a positive welcoming statement, you need to balance it out with a negative one as well, but you should avoid making respondents untangle a double negative ("I disagree with being made to feel unwelcome").

Comment: @DeNovo Good point. I've added another suggestion. Also feel free to edit if you can think of a better way to word it.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of.  To be useful, the survey needs to focus as much (or more) on how the "welcoming initiative" has actually impacted users, both new and old.  SO has already decided the answer to the "do you feel welcome" question - now we need to tell SO what effect the "welcoming initiative" has had.

Comment: @BJMyers "SO has already decided the answer to the 'do you feel welcome' question". It was an interpretation of the 'part of the community' question, and absolutely needs further questions. For one, it was quite interesting to see "minorities and women don't feel like they're part of the community" interpreted as "inexperienced people don't feel welcome". Why jump from women and minorities to "those people who don't know how to code"? It DEFINITELY needs further questions. The curve of "feeling like part of the community" vs. experience actually goes *down* as women go from early to mid career

Comment: While data on this would be great, we must remember that a question like this will be subject to serious adverse selection. People that don't feel welcome are unlikely to stick around and notice the survey, or feel inclined to contribute by filling it out.

Comment: @Anders I absolutely agree, and I think it's a problem with the survey in general. Note that I pointed this out [last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357936/developer-survey-2018-any-topic-suggestions/358084#358084) in the "impostor syndrome" question linked to in the above OP.

Answer (score 92):

My two questions:

> How many work interruptions do you experience on a daily basis?

- 0
- 1-5
- 6-10
- More than 10

> How does your employer measure your level of productivity?

- Lines of Code
- Customer satisfaction
- Effort (effort required to build the system) / Size (size of the software that is delivered)
- They don't
- I don't know
- [More Answers?]

Comment: Daily? I had occasions with more than 10 interrupts in an hour

Comment: @Mureinik Huh? Maybe I should rescale the answers then. ;-)

Comment: Or maybe my personal experience is just particularly bad :-)

Comment: Maskable or non-maskable interrupts? :) Though on a serious note, it's a good question.

Comment: "He doesn't." => "They don't." I expect a "welcoming" badge any time now...

Comment: @Mureinik And how do we count it when one interruption interrupts another interruption? Possibly as a result of [Imperious Interuptus](http://assets.amuniversal.com/74a57710a602012e2f8300163e41dd5b).

Comment: How many interrupts do I have on a daily basis? Hmm... I think [about 256](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts) but I'm pretty sure the OS takes all of them. So zero? (I think you might want to reword that to "how often are you interrupted daily at work" or something like that)

Comment: "I don't know" should be an answer. :-)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm afraid I can't give you a badge. Changed the suggestion accordingly, though. ;-)

Comment: @SJade Good point, added.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how this correlates with years at your current position. I find I get interrupted more often as my responsibilities within a company increase over time.

Comment: How many work interruptions do you experience on a daily basis? All of them! Just hang a sign that states: "Positive Feedback In Use. Do Not Perturb!"

Comment: @HABO I've considered hanging a sign on my ponytail...

Answer (score 76):

> When you work in a team, which project management methodology is used?

- **Chaos** (I will know what to do when the boss comes in and tells me)
- **Ticket-Driven** (something gets assigned to me and I do it)
- **Traditional** (I have a one-directional process where I have documented requirements to work on, with project managers and change requests. For example Waterfall or V-Model)
- **Scrum** (by the book. Really.)
- **"Scrum"** (implemented some parts of Scrum, but not all.)
- **Another form of Agile** (for example Kanban or Extreme Programming)
- **Other**
- I don't work in teams.

---

I noticed the question came up in 2018 already. But it seems very binary. With two thirds saying they do Scrum, I cannot believe they all did Scrum by the book.  Reading though [the workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and [project management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions) I simply cannot believe this number. I would be interested in how many actually do Scrum by the book and how many do "Scrum" in name only.

Comment: Feel free to add more options :)

Comment: Next to __Scrum__ and __"Scrum"__, we need *__""Scrum""__ They call it scrum, but that's where the resemblance ends.*

Comment: I didn't read books, but we have now scrum master and I am still working at company.. can someone tell me is it **scrum** or **"scrum"**?

Comment: If *you* cannot tell, then it's "Scrum". Because real Scrum includes education about what Scrum is. You cannot do Scrum, if you don't really know what it is.

Comment: @Sinatr you might find [this article](https://www.aaron-gray.com/a-criticism-of-scrum/) interesting.

Comment: @jrh That sounds like that guy never did Scrum right. For most of his criticism he doesn't even have an alternative. It's hard to estimate a task, and Scrum does that. Yeah, duh. What's the alternative? Not doing it? That's a lot of moaning and complaining and yet not a single constructive thought other than "let me do my thing". Newsflash: that's not how you work if you have more than a mom-and-pop shop.

Comment: @nvoigt I was mostly referring to [this paragraph](https://www.aaron-gray.com/a-criticism-of-scrum/#scrum-strains-the-relationship-between-management-and-developers) where Uncle Bob himself talks about how Scrum has been misinterpreted.

Comment: You could add **MMA** for Mixed Methodologies Arts aside of *Chaos*.

Comment: I've got opinions on Scrum and that article (there's business needs and efficiency issues to weigh out on both sides) but this probably isn't the place for that. I'll just say I wouldn't be surprised at all if a lot of shops claiming "Scrum" methodologies have the same problems the writer of that article had, or worse, even if the tech leads were properly trained and they had the best of intentions. Certain tensions come about while working (from above, or from other places) and not everyone is willing or able to die on certain hills forever, for better or for worse.

Comment: I like it when we call the "Scrum" category: "ScrumBut" = "its Scrum but..."

Comment: I added a question related to this question : How do you feel you are doing implementing it? Some companies poorly implement what they advertise..

Answer (score 74):

> How much time do you spend programming personal stuff outside working hours?

Added from comments:

> How much time do you spend programming personal stuff during working hours?
>
> How much time do you spend programming work stuff during personal hours?

Comment: A bit too much...

Comment: more than half of my night XD

Comment: Also, **How much time do you spend programming personal stuff during working hours?**

Comment: And, *How much time do you spend programming work stuff during personal hours*?

Comment: @Outman the 17 other upvotes clearly make me feel ... let's not say "better" but "less bad" instead -_-

Answer (score 70):

Towards the end of the survey,

```
Were you comfortable with the size of this survey?

a) Yes, it was neither too big, nor too small
b) I could've answered a few more questions
c) It was too long
```

This would help in determining the size of the next survey.

Comment: Isn't this question already a part of SO survey? I'm not sure though.

Comment: Ohh, I'm not sure too. If somebody can confirm, I can remove this answer. Thanks for your inputs @KolappanNathan :)

Comment: Based on my experience from all the previous surveys, option c can be checked by default in advance.

Comment: But what if it's this question that tips the survey over into being "too long"? Argh!

Comment: I laughed way too hard after reading this answer because it is very relatable. Every year that is

Answer (score 49):

> Some basic questions:

- What is your first programming language?

> Some health-related questions:

- How many hours of sleep you get every night? ([how important sleep is.](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/sleep-deprivation-epidemic-health-effects-tired-heart-disease-stroke-dementia-cancer-a7964156.html))

> Some team -related questions:

- Do you prefer to work in a team?

> Some question related job

- Are you happy with your job?
- Do you prefer to work from home?

> Other questions

- What do you do to accelerate your logic or speed of programming?

  - Tea
  - coffee
  - Music
  - Other things

Comment: `How many hours of sleep you get every night?` My sleep patterns are so erratic that it's kind of difficult to answer. It varies a lot depending on if there's something due the next day or not, and whether I'm on a work term (in which case my schedule is more regular) or a study term (more freedom + more random sleep schedule shifts). Also, sometimes my sleep is spread out over multiple naps throughout the day.

Comment: How much sleep I get is directly correlated with how well my children sleep (one suffers from night terrors). It has _nothing_ to do with the job :)

Answer (score 47):

> Do you work overtime, if so, how much, and are you remunerated for it?

This isn't something that was asked as part of the last survey, [despite what some claimed](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2018/03/13/stack-overflows-2018-developer-survey-reveals-programmers-mountain-overtime/). The breakdown by country would be especially interesting.

Answer (score 46):

You've found a bug in an open source library you use. Do you:

1. Work around it
2. File a bug
3. Submit a fix for it
4. I don't use open source

Comment: Not everyone uses open-source libraries, and it would also seriously depend on the bug and the library.

Comment: This was more of a tongue-in-cheek question to gauge attitudes of developers towards the tech stack they use - are they merely consumers, or do they activeily participate in it. I've added a fourth option ("I don't use open source"), but TBH, I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a developer that doesn't use at least one open source componenet **somewhere**, be it in the production code, the testing code, the toolchain around the build process, etc.

Comment: "Complain on SO" is missing

Comment: "Tell SO the problem is urgent" is missing.

Comment: Probably needs another option to `Drop the library altogether`

Comment: Of course a person might do more one of these actions... I know I have when encountering bugs in MS Office object models.

Comment: **option 5** :  make a whole new open source lib that solves that one (or several) problem(s).

Comment: @DavidG with [this graphic](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/006/725/desk_flip.jpg) to go along :-)

Comment: `Look in the bug tracker to see if it's already been reported`

Comment: Add 5. Report to the maintainer

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown that's essentially what "file a bug" means, assuming the maintainer gives a damn and reviews his (or her) bugs

Comment: @Mureinik hm I see.

Answer (score 45):

When you commute to work, how do you spend your time?

- I don't commute
- Don't bother me, I'm sleeping
- Read the newspaper
- Read a book
- Browse SO on a phone
- Browse SO on a laptop
- Visit hot network questions
- Listen to podcasts
- Listen to radio
- Listening to (my own collection of) music
- listen to other passengers loudly broadcasting intimate details of their personal life
- Do work
- Talk with passengers
- Be bored
- Fully concentrated on driving my car/bike
- Other:

Comment: I wouldnt suggest any of these whilst driving a motorvehicle!

Comment: @Luuklag: I expect a retro-fit self-driving widget will be available for all motor vehicles soon!

Comment: Shouldn't it be a Library, so it can fit all makes and models? @halfer

Comment: @Luuklag: yes, hopefully there will be a developer API, and hacker drivers can plug in a Raspberry Pi `:-)`

Comment: Can you add `Listen to podcasts` top the list? I certainly do that and I suspect many others do too.

Comment: "Listen to the radio"? I would guess a lot of people going by car do that. Because of all your above options, 90% will get my a ticket or even jail time.

Comment: @nvoigt not wanting that to happen. Option added.

Comment: _"Listening to (my own collection of) music"_. I my experience, it's significantly different from listening to the radio.

Comment: I'm now wondering of the podcast item should be it's own question. I'll add an answer and see if gets any interest.

Comment: @DavidG asking which podcasts you listen to? It would have my vote.

Comment: @rene Since there's a bazillion of them, I've [limited it to category](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375973/1663001) but I'd be super interested in the actual podcasts people are consuming.

Comment: Isn't it either "listen to radio/music" or "listen to other passengers loudly broadcasting intimate details of their personal life"? Which in turn means there's a popular option missing: "loud, braindead conversations with my partner or best friend over phone".

Comment: @nvoigt Not everyone commutes by a vehicle they drive/etc.  If you're using mass transit, or are a passenger in a vehicle being driven by someone else (car pool, lyft, etc) your options for spending the time are a lot more diverse.   This question might benefit from being paired with a "how do you commute" one.

Comment: @DanNeely I am aware of that and I did not ask for removing any option. It was just very centered on public transport and it's more broad now.

Comment: @Lundin I think asking developers to qualify themselves if they are braindead (conversation wise) is in conflict with the former be nice policy and the current CoC. I added the *listen to* option though as that fits my sense of humor ...

Comment: @Lundin maybe there's more to it than it seems, and the other popular option is actually "see how much I can annoy the other passengers"

Comment: If we have to make a full list, I'd say there should also be: browsing other sites (there's not only SO/SE!), playing games, watching videos... But I actually think the list is already too long and should be trimmed somehow.

Comment: Suggest two more options: (1) watch films or recorded TV or videos alongside the Podcast options. (2) play computer games.

Answer (score 43):

General requests:

- Don't assume that the person taking the survey lives in the US. Drop all US-specific things like "benefits: health insurance", which in nonsensical in many countries.
- Please shorten the survey. The 30+ minutes it took last year is far too long! Preferably by cutting out every question which isn't about programming or SO.

Comment: "Too long", and yet over 100k people filled it out.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I remember started filling it out, then had to leave the computer because it just took too long. Then when I had time for it, I had to start over. I would imagine this is a common situation and when that happens, most people would just go "ok screw this survey".

Comment: Maybe if they had a checkpoint where after 8 minutes, the basic survey was done and sent, but you could continue the extended survey for another 22 minutes?

Comment: *Drop all US-specific things like "benefits: health insurance"* Not all companies offer all types of benefits anyway. If they were to limit benefits questions to only those offered by all companies globally, the list would be empty.

Comment: @Lundin: Suggested Edit: - Please add some sort of progress indicator on every page showing how much is done and how much is remaining. - Cover all important question (cannot suggest the criteria to define 'important') first. - There should be an option/way to skip entire page/section. I know there is already an option to "not answering"/"skip this question".

Comment: Agree with @BlackVegetable. The survey should be divided in sections. There should be commit point after each section. This will help to complete the survey in steps.

Comment: Don't agree on the length point (I have _hours_ to waste during work time), but definitely on the US-centricity. If you don't already, then getting the survey reviewed by people all around the world would be good, before publishing.

Comment: @AmitJoshi They used to have an indicator before the survey became dynamic. Now that which questions you're shown depends on your answers, that's harder to do. Also, I they are probably worried that doing, "1/N possible questions" would scare people off, especially if it's impossible for any one person to end up seeing all N questions. They could update the total number as you go but that would probably be confusing.

Answer (score 41):

**In which of the following *human* languages do you have any proficiency?**

[languages given here just as an example]

1. English
2. German
3. Russian
4. Japanese
5. Dinka

etc., plus write-in options

I'd be interested in answering questions like

- Are developers more multilingual than non-developers?
- Are developers who are more multilingual than their peers more successful? more productive? more educated?
- Just how many developers around the world only speak English?

I suppose taking the survey in English would bias the sample somewhat.

Comment: Was there a reasonable criterion in the selection of those 5 languages? There are not more Japanese speakers in the world than there are, for instance,  Portuguese speakers.

Comment: I know a *lot* of people who think they're fluent in English and actually aren't. :/

Comment: For this to have any relevance, you would have to compare programmers from country x, with average people from country x. And so you would have to make a second survey for non-programmers.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the fraction of users of the other-language Stack Overflow sites who also speak English.  I don't think there are any plans to translate the survey, but a simple one-question survey specifically for those sites (and that links to the English SO survey if they say they're proficient) would be useful market research (which is, after all, what the survey is about).

Comment: Most non-US/UK people are at least bilingual (especially if they're filling in a survey in English). Most US/UK people only speak one language. Developer salaries are highest in the US (as seen in previous surveys). Thus, the conclusion from this will be that you earn more money if you are not bilingual.

Comment: @E_net4 absolutely no criteria there at all. I just wanted to list some human languages to make it obvious I wasn't talking about C#, Python, etc.

Comment: @Lundin I'd actually expect this to be fairly widely studied external to SO. For example, the Australian Bureau of Statistics collects data on languages spoken in the home as part of the national census.

Comment: @CrisLuengo part of my motivation here is that I'd like to examine the assumption that "most [anglophone] developers only speak one language". I'm an Australian working in Australia and within my technical team of 8 we have speakers of Mandarin, German, Italian, Polish, Punjabi, Farsi, Hebrew, Spanish, and probably a few more.

Comment: @CrisLuengo also you're quite correct re: the national salary effect. I'm hoping that the stack exchange data scientist folks can solve that one for us.

Comment: Adding a caveat like "what languages other than your native language(s) do you speak" could be useful.

Comment: Duh, I speak JavaScript as a human language, too! Now please `var myVar = () => {if (true) return this;}; console.log(7)`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms 7.

Comment: I think this is an important question to help promote [inclusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380175/developer-survey-inclusion-metric-natural-language).

Comment: @DanDascalescu great minds think alike! Maybe next year...

Answer (score 40):

Do you ask, read, or answer programming questions on sites aside from Stack Overflow? If so which ones?

Comment: I'd prefer to rephrase this slightly; there may be sites which are not specifically programming or Q&A sites but on which programming questions could be asked. So more like: "Do you read, ask, or answer programming questions on sites aside from Stack Overflow?"

Comment: @Justin that wording does seem better. Added it to the answer.

Comment: @Justin Like on BodyBuilding.com forums. That's where I used get all of my programming help before SO. /s

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/stackoverflow/

Answer (score 38):

> How do you feel about "visual coding" or drag-and-drop programming?

Comment: ...and you should answer it by drag'n'dropping words to form a sentence:)

Comment: This is a great question imo!

Comment: @Roberrrt I came up with it when I was thinking about how so many kids are taught drag-and-drop, and never actually realize they'll need to type to be a programmer.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms fixing 100$ visually coded website themes was my primary source of freelance work for a full year when studying.

Answer (score 35):

> How many monitors do you use (which makes you feel comfortable)?

- 1
- 2
- 3 or more

> Do you have a personal tech blog to share knowledge?

Comment: _"Do you have personal tech blog to share knowledge?"_ Other than _"X% of users have a blog"_, I don't really see the point of that question.

Comment: Another option:
- 1 + my laptop screen

Comment: @Marco That's two monitors.

Comment: How many monitors do you use (which makes you feel comfortable)? | I often use 1... but my ideal would be 2 | Do you have personal tech blog to share knowledge? | i'm working on it....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "which makes you feel comfortable"? Can you clarify?

Comment: If we're going to ask this, it might be interesting to capture a longer tail of answers? "How many monitors do you use?" [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6 or more]

Answer (score 34):

Do you feel that your superiors or coworkers value your contributions as a programmer?

Comment: I read that and I hear "Imposter syndrome". is this what this question is? I agree it'd a really important question.

Answer (score 24):

> How many of the developers that you know have an active Stack Overflow account?

Options:

1. All of them
2. Most of them
3. Half of them
4. A few of them
5. I'm the only one
6. I don't know/I'm unsure

Comment: I think "I don't know/I'm unsure" should also be an option.

Comment: Everyone I know (that's a developer) uses Stack Overflow but I have absolutely no idea how many of them have accounts. Somewhat of a weird question, imo.

Comment: @chevybow every people that was in my team I knew if they have a SO account or not. I think this question is good to know if most of the developers only use the site and does not have any interest to create an account

Comment: Not everyone who participates in the developer survey has an active Stack Overflow account. Some may use other networks primarily or only like taking the survey without participating in the site. It would be better to keep the second to last answer focused by saying "None of them"

Answer (score 22):

**How many times in your career have you moved due to your job?**

My curiosity comes from age/experience vs. travel - with telecommuting being more and more viable I wonder how it is taking its toll on the work force.

Are higher-level people flown out for in-person meetings? Are they trusted at home? Are in-person people who would commit to a life change, such as a move, paid more over time? etc.

Comment: Interesting question, but the phrase "moved due to your job" has many possible interpretations. Some of them are: Moves that stay with the same employer where the old office and job remain open. Moves where the old office closes and the company relocates. Changes of employer to get a better (more money, changed work/life balance, shorter commute, etc) job. Forced job moves due to redundancy or company restructuring.

Answer (score 20):

How does your company/employer contribute to your professional development? (check all that apply)

- Not applicable: I'm self-employed, so I do what I want and can afford.
- Sponsors technical presentations
- Sponsors reading circles
- Sponsors lunch and learns
- Provides time to learn during normal working hours
- Will pay for offsite training
- Will buy books for self-learning
- Will pay for online learning courses
- Will fully pay for College or University classes
- Will partially pay for College or University classes

Comment: I like this. Suggestion: anything related to the company paying for education could possibly be condensed to, "Company offers employees an education budget". I don't believe many companies always "fully" or "partially" pay for college coursework regardless of tuition cost.

Comment: @JakeReece My thinking is that an employer either doesn't pay at all, they pay some, or they pay it all. In my experience, most employers have a tuition re-reimbursement program that is the max allowed to be deducted by the IRS (which would be a partial pay scenario). I think it would be interesting to see how many companies are willing to fully pay for someone's education.

Answer (score 19):

Not too sure whether this got covered in previous surveys already, but the "working from home" subject might be interesting, e.g.:

- Does your company allow you to work from home?
- Do you like working from home?
- How often a week do you work from home?

Answer (score 17):

Three general suggestions:

#### Follow up on "part of the community" question

Test your assumptions from last year's ["part of the community" question](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#community-do-developers-consider-themselves-part-of-the-stack-overflow-community)

This was mentioned in an earlier answer, but I'd be particularly careful here to use a good set of questions that follow survey best practices, and hit it from a few different angles. E.g., one conclusion was:

> [Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)

The following statements with a likert agree-disagree response could help you learn more about that. Keep the "part of the community" question as a comparison (obviously).

1. I feel welcome to ask and answer questions on Stack Overflow (or maybe to participate in, rather than to ask and answer questions)
2. The Stack Overflow community welcomes people like me

This would, on its face, measure your concern (people don't feel welcome), but I'm not a huge fan of the use of the word welcome here. For one, by using the "welcome" word you may be measuring a mix of the actual thing you're trying to measure (whether people feel welcome) and the response of users to a set of new features (the welcoming effort), which you should also be measuring, but more explicitly. In this case, it might be useful to use different phrasing, or slightly adjust what you're trying to measure. This has the added benefit of interrogating why **experienced** women and minorities don't feel like part of the community (instead of just directing programs and features at **inexperienced** users). For example, you could use:

3. The Stack Overflow community values people like me
4. People value my help when I answer questions on Stack Overflow (with an opt out for haven't answered a question)
5. People help me when I ask questions on Stack Overflow (with an opt out for haven't asked a question)

These questions would, of course, need to be analyzed by both experience and demographics.

Free response questions could help you generate more specific hypotheses about *what* makes people feel like they are or aren't part of the community. You could use these to develop better questions for the 2020 developer survey

#### Follow up on free response items from 2018 survey

Don't let your free answer response items [like this one](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#community-what-words-do-developers-use-to-describe-stack-overflow) from last year go to waste. Their utility is largely hypothesis generating. Follow this up by developing new specific questions. For example, one hypothesis drawn from a common word analysis was

> Developers were largely positive about Stack Overflow, focusing on the helpful nature of the community

Test this with the following three questions, phrased as statements the respondent can agree or disagree with on, e.g., a 5 point Likert scale. These questions can be phrased differently, but the point is to measure the valence of the respondents feelings regarding (1) the helpfulness of community and (2) the site, and (3) more objectively identify whether the respondent was helped. Looking at the concordance/discordance of these responses gives you a strong sense about your strengths and weaknesses here.  You might consider tweaking (3) so that, rather than a statement with a likert on agree/disagree, it asks how many times Stack Overflow helped the respondent solve a problem in (time period). Time period should be shorter for this version of the question, and analysis should also involve normalizing by frequency of use (presumably you're asking that question elsewhere).

1. The Stack Overflow community is helpful
2. Stack Overflow is a helpful website
3. Stack Overflow helped me solve a problem at some point in the last year

That's just one example, but generally, it's a good idea to look at hypotheses drawn from whatever analyses were done on the free response questions from last year, pick some important ones, and interrogate them with questions that test those hypotheses.

#### Interrogate the relationship between the users and the brand, or institution that is SE

There are questions about how respondents relate to the main product (Q&A) and how they relate to each other (community). I would encourage you to also ask questions about how respondents relate to the brand or SE as an entity that produces the product they use. The language here will be in large part determined by your own branding decisions (e.g., you may not want to ask how respondents feel about the SE brand if part of your brand is that you are not a slick, inhuman, corporate entity), so I'm not going to suggest specific wording. Regardless, it will be useful to ask 100,000s of developers about whether they feel SO is responsive, on their side, just wants to make money off of them, is cold and unfeeling, etc.  Right now you have a sense of that from recent meta discussions, but these are from orders of magnitude fewer individuals than respond to the developer survey.

Comment: I commented elsewhere, but having "don't know" in the Likert scale, specially in this kind of questions, would help figure out the awareness about the sentiment on the questionee.

Comment: @Braiam the survey question writers here seem to have a good handle on how to ask these kinds of questions :) I'm just trying to nudge them toward addressing these topics, and mentioning the easy to miss pitfall that specifically asking about "feeling welcome" might measure something other than how welcome respondents feel.

Comment: Yeah, I know. My worries are what interpretation they give to the results, which is derived from these answers. I try to always include the ambivalent response on all instruments I implement.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not entirely sure, but I think last year's survey included a neutral option in likert scales, and the exact wording  ("neutral" vs. "unknown" vs. "neither agree nor disagree") doesn't seem to make a difference in responses

Comment: I think there are times when you want a neutral (neither agree nor disagree) response and times when want a don't know response, and they are different.  Sometimes you suspect people use those responses to avoid saying what they think because of social acceptability bias.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps not relevant for everyone, like students or people working on small personal projects, but something along the lines of:

> How long did it take your most-recently-released commit to reach your users?

or

> On average, how long does it take you to get a commit in front of your users?

Comment: Actually a substancial part of the survey is geared towards commercially-employed developers. But a good question to add.

Comment: Are you saying that it's only for commercially-employed developers because you assume other developers don't  work on projects that have release cycles?

Comment: This question seems related to agile methods. Many projects have a long development period before any customer sees anything.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - good point, although I still think this could be interesting information, especially if the responses were compared to those for a question about methodologies that I've seen also suggested here. I'd hope for something like the 'developers who use spaces are paid more' from a couple of years ago - "developers' salaries are inversely proportional to the length of their release cycles", maybe? :D

Comment: I omitted to say that I agree it is an interesting question. But it needs careful writing to cover the differences between agile and long term development methods.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - agreed. I've tried a few times to think of better ways of wording it, but failed every time :) Your (entirely accurate) observation only makes it harder :) Thankfully that's someone else's problem though, if they want to use the question!

Answer (score 16):

> What percentage of your developing time is spent learning new technology or skills?

Comment: ... and are you able to use those new skills in your work? I have been on a few training courses which where unrelated to the work I was doing and the needs of project I was on.

Comment: My original thinking was more along the lines of trying to get the gist of how much of their time, most developers are learning new stuff in their day-to-day work. Some will be applying their existing knowledge to solve problems, others will be spending a good chunk of their time doing things for the first time with new tools; either learning or refining skills. Some jobs I've spent almost exclusively learning - other jobs I've done lots of debugging but little new tech.

Answer (score 15):

When progressing in your career, what attracts you the most?

- Technical Position
- Management Position
- A combination of both Technical and Management responsibilities

Comment: the company, the team, the topics or simply $$$ / €€€

Comment: What  attracts me is how much they pay!

Answer (score 14):

Are you required to carry a pager or cell phone outside of normal working hours as part of your job? If so, are you compensated to carry it? How often are you called into work?

Comment: If you are also required to answer the said pager/phone, then that's what's referred to as "on call", and should be compensated.

Comment: Where I work the senior devs are, in turns, required to be "on weekend duty". But that's only during the summer time (peak traffic). Maybe it would be good to add some variation to this question like "yes, but only in certain periods"

Answer (score 13):

Are you usually working on a side project (for yourself or your client) beside your full-time job?

Answer (score 13):

I'd love to know how "Dress Code" policies correlate to the existing questions in the survey.

Perhaps it is more or less likely to be subjected to a smart dress code for particular languages, or in companies that pay more/less? Woudn't it be interesting to discover whether dress code is an indicator for bigger and more important things!

Comment: I wish showers were an indicator of pay scale.

Answer (score 12):

### Where did you come from?

I haven't always been a developer, and I'm curious how many other people changed careers to get into programming, and if there are any trends as far as what they were doing before.

I was thinking maybe something like

- I've been a developer for my entire career
- I don't have a career yet, I'm still in school/just a kid
- I was a _______ before I was a developer (select from list of career categories)
- I'm still not a developer, I'm a ________ (same list)

Comment: The list would need to have an "other" option since practically every field has people switching to be a software developer. Coal mining, for instance.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Yeah, I think so too. I was thinking it would be best to have a short list of fairly broad categories, so it would be likely to cover most people. Maybe something like [this](https://www.recruiter.com/careers/). (I'm not familiar with that site, it was just my first google result for "career categories" and I thought the list there looked okay). But yeah, there's probably always going to be an "other", even if the categories are broad. Were you a coal miner before? ;-)

Comment: Nah, I learned to code when I was 7, I was just referring to [BitSource](https://www.bitsourceky.com).

Comment: @StephenLeppik And now I have *that* song stuck in my head. "I was born one morning when the sun didn't shine, picked up my shovel and walked to the mine..."

Comment: @DavyM never heard it.

Comment: @StephenLeppik [Here you go](https://youtu.be/-GBBPWjNrwY); or just the [lyrics](http://www.insideout-acappella.com/lyrics/coalmine.html) if you don't want to listen to the whole thing.

Comment: @DavyM I already don't want to risk an earworm, millennials have enough of our own.

Comment: @StephenLeppik or the list could just be [very thorough](https://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes_stru.htm).

Answer (score 11):

I think that a question around how the new "be nice to new people" CoC has affected older members of SO (following a question about whether the poster is new or not) - there seems to have been a lot of push-back around the new attitude SO now seems to have regarding what constitutes being rude etc. I would be interested in seeing if this is a vocal minority or a more pressing issue.

Similarly, a question about how *newer* members have felt since the recent policy changes came into effect would be interesting.

Answer (score 11):

How many hours a week do you spend in meetings?

Comment: Sometimes we have 1h+ long meetings discussing how late we are and what countermeasures we must take to at least prevent going over budget, while we could've spent that time in something useful, like for example finishing the project.

Answer (score 10):

Do you regularly attend any developer events/conferences?

Examples:

- Microsoft Ignite
- Microsoft Build
- Oracle Code
- SmashingConf San Francisco
- Philly.Net CodeCamp
- etc.

Or, the question could be "how many per year, 0, 1-3, 4-8, 9+"

Comment: I think simply asking how many per year would be better than trying to isolate specific conferences. There are simply too many conferences/meetups around the world to list such that you could reliably avoid bias in the results.

Comment: I agree, I was just giving examples of what kind of conferences I was talking about.

Answer (score 10):

Related to attending developer conferences, how about asking

> Do you belong to any technical Meetup or Local User Groups?
>
> - 0
> - 1-2
> - 3-4
> - 5 or more

and

> How many meetings do you attend, on average?
>
> - More than once a week
> - Once a week
> - 1-2 times a month
> - Once every 2-3 months
> - 1-2 times a year
> - Less than once a year

Answer (score 10):

Not a *topic* suggestion per se, but:

Regarding the "Better acknowledgement of freelancers / part-timers / hobbyists", please also don't forget about people like academic researchers in computer-related fields. Many of us are not strictly developers, but writing code is still a significant part of our job description. However, a lot of the "does your company do X?" questions simply don't make much sense when talking about a university.

Related to that, there's also grad students - where I live, we are essentially (in many cases also literally) part-time employees of the university, so that's what I picked last year as my employment status - but again, there was some stuff in the survey that didn't really apply.

At the very least, it would be useful to have a "this doesn't really apply to my current situation" option for every question.

---

And, a more specific suggestion:

> How big a part of your job description is writing code (and related tasks)?

- I am a software developer, it's what the entire job is about
- I am *not* a software developer, but I have an IT-related job and writing code is an important part of it.
- It's one part of my job, but not the only one. I spend a lot of my time doing things not related to programming.
- Not very - I sometimes write code to make my work easier or to automate certain tasks, but it's not an official part of my job.
- Completely irrelevant - I don't do any programming at all as part of my main job.

Answer (score 9):

**What kind of podcasts do you listen to on a regular basis?**

1. I don't listen to podcasts
2. The Stack Overflow podcast (!)
3. Tech
4. Business
5. Comedy
6. Education
7. Games/hobbies
8. Health
9. Music
10. Politics
11. Science
12. Sports

May even be interesting to ask people to list their favourite(s)?

Comment: This assumes that podcasts are widely popular. I personally don't know a single person who listens to podcasts _regularly_. Since the question also requires multiple-choice, I'm not sure what the results will tell us? I don't see how this fits into a "Developer Survey".

Comment: @sboesch It doesn't assume anything, it may be that 99% of people answer with "I don't listen to podcasts". Personally I know lots of people who do listen to them, myself included. However, the latest research suggests that 26% of US citizens are consuming them and I believe that number is similar in the UK. Isn't that significant enough to be useful?

Comment: Also don't forget that answers to this question can be correlated with others. For example, how many devs in Australia also listen? Does geography affect the numbers? Age? Experience? Job title?

Comment: Fair enough, haven't noticed such a growth in the past years. But I still don't see how this correlates to us as developers. One could also ask, how many of us watch TV/Youtube or read books on a regular basis.

Comment: The Stack Overflow podcast does not count as it is down to one episode every 6-8 months. Once per month would be the minimum to be considered a real active podcast.

Comment: @sboesch Well for a start, It's about learning how developers consume information and even how they learn about new tech. Being a dev is far more than sitting in front of a screen all day, I'd like to get to know the people behind all that.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah, the SO podcast was really just a joke entry.

Answer (score 9):

Past surveys have asked what benefits people want and had them rank them in order of importance. I'd like to see how satisfied people are with their benefits. This would require two questions:

**Question 1**

Which employer-provided benefits have you used in the past year? This includes benefits your employer may be required to provide by law. Please check all that apply:

- Vacation/Sick Leave
- Parental Leave
- Health/Dental/Vision Insurance
- Life/Short Term/Long Term/Disability Insurance
- Dependent Care Assistance
- Retirement Plan
- Stock Options
- Tuition Reimbursement
- Remote Work
- Flexible Work Hours
- On-site childcare
- Other on-site services (ex. on-site gym)
- Commute benefits
- Retail Discounts/Reimbursements

**Question 2** (for each checked benefit)

How satisfied are you with [benefit]?

- Very Satisfied
- Satisfied
- Somewhat Satisfied
- Somewhat Dissatisfied
- Dissatisfied
- Very Dissatisfied

NOTE: This would only be shown to users who previously stated that they're employed by a business/organization so unemployed/self-employed users won't see it at all. Not applicable isn't an necessary option.

If there should be a survey question for self-employed/freelance users about benefits it should be separate since they'd have to pay for those themselves.

Comment: I like the question, but I think it will be heavily influenced by country and we have to be very careful to word the questions. Where I live, for example "sick leave" is not a *benefit*, the employer is legally *required* to pay me in full for every day I can present a doctors note. I might be dissatisfied with 24 days paid leave (vacation) because that's the legal minimum only. My employer will pay into the retirement plan, but that's not optional and every other employer would be legally required to do the exact same thing. Me checking boxes and you checking boxes would mean different things

Comment: *I might be dissatisfied with 24 days paid leave (vacation) because that's the legal minimum only.* @nvoight But that's exactly what I want to know: You're unhappy with your paid leave benefits. That your government requires a certain amount is irrelevant; the question isn't asking *why* you're unsatisfied. Someone else with fewer days may be perfectly happy with it and someone with even more may be upset because of the hoops they have to jump through in order to get their leave approved.

Answer (score 9):

In this era, programming languages and technologies are improving frequently and many times we need to change our preferred programming language, so the question that comes to my mind is:

**How comfortable you are with switching programming languages and technologies?**

Answer (score 9):

> Do you still work on a legacy application* at your workplace?

*Application built using obsolete tech-stack.

This will help to understand how fast organizations are adapting to newer technologies.

Comment: Interesting, but it probably needs some rewording/rephrase. The "still" in the question implies it's in the current time while some developer may have worked on a legacy application in the (recent) past.

Comment: Good question, also add to it, how large are management willing to let the backlog of issues on the legacy product grow to before realising nobody wants the replacement product because the legacy one is so poor and not maintained, catch 22.

Answer (score 9):

Here are My set of Questions:

> How much time do you spend in a typical week Learning a New
>   Language/Skill?

- 0
- < 1 Hour
- 1 - 4 Hours
- More than 4 Hours

> What is your Method for Learning a New Language/Skill if required?

- MOOCs
- Free Sources/Google
- Books
- Instructor led Classes

Answer (score 7):

> If you're working remotely, are you working based on your own time zone every day?

Comment: Good question, but needs a little more refinement maybe: when I worked remotely, I started working at anywhere between 8 AM and 1 PM. If I'm starting at 1 PM, is that still "based on my time zone"? ;) I had a number of colleagues who worked a couple of hours 'behind' me, but that wasn't the reason I would start at 1 PM.

Comment: Could also ask "How many days a week do you work remotely" (0-7)

Comment: @TrueWill I didn't got it completely. There are 2 chances. One, the person may work 4 days remotely and 1 day from office or if it is contract based, may be works in a total of 3-4 days

Comment: @Marco good point. I'm based on India and while reading remote job posts, I often see 2 things, either _work based on your own timezone, and you should be available to a weekly meeting_ or _you must work based on PST_. But the starting time does matter as you said

Answer (score 7):

**How much of your time do you spend managing a team?**

Or, alternatively:

**How much of your time do you spend on non-development activities?**

Answer (score 7):

What kind of specification do you get for a project?

- 300 page document
- 1 page document
- Thumbnail of a single screenshot of something they saw once in a magazine
- A manager runs past your office shouting something unintelligible and you're meant to know what they were asking for and that they were talking to you.

Answer (score 7):

Do you work on weekend?
Do you have a rule of avoiding any work during weekends?

Answer (score 6):

## How many days will it take before you forget the wireframe of your source-code?

Developers who work with multiple projects may often leave behind the source-code untouched for a while. It would be interesting to know how many days will the source code reside on the developers RAM before it subsides. I hope I am not alone on this query.

Comment: Wow this! Is that what you call it? I was thinking 'context switching'. I would love to work on many projects, but find the context switch such a tremendous effort, like a freight train switching tracks. Keeping 10 things in your head at once is harder than it seems! Glad I'm not the only one with this problem. Even just 2-3 days and going back to the other project, I'm like "What's going on here?"

Comment: I agree, questions about context switching should be considered by stackoverflow. Context switching though is more of personal handling of the process switching to multiple things. In essence it is different with the question I suggested because it is about the latency and turn-around time of context switching. But yeah @Chloe I think you need to submit a separate suggestion on that.

Answer (score 6):

> What is your preferred working position?

- Sitting on a chair
- Lay down on sofa and working on Laptop
- Standing Table

Answer (score 5):

What are your typical working hours?

(For professional developers, i.e. people who do development as part of their job, this would mean the hours of their job. For non-professional developers, e.g. students, hobbyists, this would mean the typical hours they tend to spend programming.)

I'm not sure if the survey supports an answer form like this, but maybe some kind of number line or something where you can mark the range e.g. 9am -> 5pm. Which hopefully can support answers where people's working hours are broken up over the day.

It would be interesting to know whether certain types of roles trend towards non-standard working hours (e.g. maybe DBAs being on after-hours support).

Answer (score 5):

Here are my two cents:

- Item(Add): **Selenium**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
- Item(Add): **Protractor**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
- Item(Add): **TestNG**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
- Item(Add): **Maven**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
- Item(Add): **Gradle**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
- Item(Add): **Jenkins**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Frameworks, Libraries, and Tools`
- Item(Add): **Jython**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Programming, Scripting, and Markup Languages`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Languages`
- Item(Add): **Dart**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Programming, Scripting, and Markup Languages`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Languages`
- Item(Add): **Tcl**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Programming, Scripting, and Markup Languages`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Languages`
- Item(Add): **Elixir**

  - Within the following Sections:
  - `Programming, Scripting, and Markup Languages`
  - `Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Languages`
- Section: Site Use

  - Topic(Add): **Did you share your Developer Story with your current/next Employer/Colleagues/Groups to showcase your work?**
- Section: Site Use

  - Topic(Add): **Do you feel your Developer Story helped you to showcase your work with your current/next Employer/Colleagues/Groups?**
- Section(Add): Stack Overflow Jobs

  - Topic(Add): **Are the openings shown in Jobs you might like section relevant to you?**
- Section(Add): Stack Overflow Jobs

  - Topic(Add): **Were the openings shown in Jobs you might like section helpful to you?**

Comment: Jython is not a programming language

Answer (score 4):

> How much you satisfied with current company environment?

- Very Satisfied
- Satisfied
- Ok
- Dissatisfied
- Very Dissatisfied

> Why____________?

Comment: Free form responses are highly unusual in such a large survey because there's often no time or way to group things by common denominators.

Comment: @TylerH free form responses gives you better result, understanding, and ideas.

Comment: @MayurShah But I we receive say 1 Lakh free form responses, how are we going to group them to interpret a meaningful graph? MCQ and Checkboxes are best suited for this survey.

Comment: @KolappanNathan Not all free form responses are useful, it's depends on what you are targeting.

Comment: @MayurShah This link (https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018) shows how the data from the previous survey is interpreted. For your question the data needs to be interpreted as 20% because of company location, etc...  In free form one person would type company is located in remote area, office is in remote, office location in rural etc... It will be difficult to group these results automatically (Manual work for such a large survey is not ideal). While in MCQ these answers come under 1 option "company location". MCQ with possible options & an other box is better. That is my opinion.

Comment: @MayurShah Yes, if we have unlimited time, space, and resources. In a statistical environment, though, you want as closed and narrow a scope as possible to help make your data meaningful in the aggregate. Most surveyors typically provide a *single*, catch-all option as a substitute for free-form responses: "other".

Answer (score 4):

I do not have a suggestion for specific questions. Rather, I would like to suggest a survey outcome feature for which I hope you can formulate the appropriate questions.

**I would like to see a survey feature that allows me to see the career progress of software engineers as a time series in order to let current engineers (and aspiring ones) understand if they are on the right track.** You can imagine such a feature would have time (years) elapsed from college graduation on the x-axis, while salary, total comp, engineering title, or other objective metrics would be on the y-axis.

An alternative version of the graph would show career progress / salary increase over time from attaining a specific (or any) new skill, new technology, new degree, or new certification.

The time series should be calibrated to region, of course.

I know that is a bit a vague, but I think if you can create such a chart, it would help out all engineers.

Answer (score 3):

Which of the following does your team do prior to starting a software project:

- Write an extensive design document
- Create formal UML diagrams
- Have a quick whiteboard meeting
- Develop User Stories for Scrum
- Other?

Comment: I would add "Ensuring there is a good testing plan"

Answer (score 3):

### Acceptable licenses

*Are you allowed to use open-source libraries in your products?*

With choices:

- Yes, including copyleft licenses such as GPL
- Yes, but only permissive licenses such as Apache
- No, commercial supported libraries only
- There is no license policy
- Does not apply: I do not work on software products

*This Q is interesting because:* I see certain companies to suffer from paranoia when it comes to the GPL. But there are great tools such as R that are GPL only. I'd like to see some stats how many developers have to suffer from their legal departments.

Comment: There should be an option saying "I work on a open-source code base. I'm only allowed to use open-source library"

Answer (score 2):

Would love to see "Version control" section split into "Loved/Dreaded/Wanted", like languages in 2018.

Normally, a VCS is something imposed on you by the organization; a few people make the decision and everybody has to use it for years or decades.

So just the fact of usage doesn't tell you much about the quality of the product; but the developers' feelings do.

Answer (score 0):

Would be interesting with some more numbers on the #metoo movement.

- Have you experienced sexual harassment at your company.
- Have you witnessed sexual harassment at your company.
- Have your company made any improvements since #metoo movement started.

There is probably a better way to phrase these kind of questions to cause as little unease and controversy as possible.

Comment: Have you been convicted of false sexual harassment? (add?)

Comment: Convictions I would assume are out of scope since it is no longer in the work place.

Answer (score -1):

Rate the quality of the codebase you work on?

Do your managers value the quality of their codebase or just you?

What is the average unit test code coverage of your codebase?

Does your company use code metrics or code analysis?

Does your company have guidelines for code quality?

Does your company have check-in rules?

Does your company always expect it's developers to put in extra hours due to an estimate over-run?

Rate the difficulty of obtaining business requirements from the business users or managers?

How often are business requirements changed with-out adjusting the estimate?

Does your company exploit younger workers by making or allowing them to work more than 40 hours a week?

Does your company actively mentor younger developers?

Do you have peers senior to you to learn from?

Does your company ever train you or provide you training classes or materials?

How many hours a week do you spend trying to fix/solve a problem because of a cryptic error message?

Answer (score -1):

Do you believe your company truly implements the development model they promote?

Reasoning behind this question : Some companies say they they are "agile" but when you look at how the work is done , truth is that they are still implementing Waterfall methodology. I am interested to see if this happens often.

Answer (score -2):

### Number of tools typically stacked

I observe an increasing amount of *stacking*, i.e., plugging one tool into another into another into another... Until everything breaks, because some glue inbetween was too fragile, some API changed etc.
This has become particularly bad in big data, where people stacked R into Hadoop, and then wondered why performance is horrible when you fire up new R interpreters repeatedly and serialize all the data repeatedly to text...

There are of course some stacks that have proven well (LAMP, for example) but usually these working stacks are very low level components (OS, Webserver, Database, Language) unlike above Hadoop example...

So I'd like to see a question if people **experience stuff to break the more tools/libraries they use**. No idea if this can be quantified easily, and if we can see a sweet spot before things begin to break too often.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to ask about volunteering.
Do you spend significant amounts of time volunteering as a programmer?
a. 10+ hours per week
b. 10+ hours per month
c. 10+ hours per quarter
d. 10+ hours per year
e. I volunteer a significant amount of time, but not as a programmer
f. This answer provided for people who feel like their job is tricking them into working more than they're paid for
g. No

[Multiple Choice] What do you volunteer at?
a. Political campaigns or policitical organization
b. School or community organizations
c. Religious organizations
d. Disaster relief
e. Disease- or disorder-focused organization
f. Terror cell
g. Other

[Assign weights] What motivates your volunteering?
a. Our political leaders are travesties and embarrassments and I am committed to unseating them
b. A desire to be of service
c. To improve the entities of which I am a part
d. To meet or deepen my relationship with people
e. Per the terms of my release
f. For moral superiority
g. Other

Answer (score -3):

> How many hours a week do you work "off the clock" or otherwise outside of your expected work contribution?

Answer (score -3):

Here are my suggestions:

How often do you buy a course about software development ?

- once a month
- 2-5 time per month
- I never buy, I just read documentation and go to stackoverflow when it's need.

How many software development related event do you usually go in one year ?

- None
- 1-3
- 4-6
- 7+

About your immediate superior, he/she usually accepts your suggestions ?

- Always
- Often
- Sometimes
- Never

If your team uses Scrum, how long does your daily meeting last ?

- 1-15 minutes
- 15-30 minutes
- 30-60 minutes
- 1h+

While you're developing, which of the factors bellow are more annoying to you ?

- Peoples talking around me
- Uncomfortable chair
- Slow pc
- Slow internet
- Frequent changes in the requirements
- Leak of knowledge of your superiors about the software development process
- A coworker who ask things you often
- Work with poorly documented requirements

If you use pomodoro technique, what do you do in your break ?

- Listen to music
- Open social networks
- Find something to buy
- Get up and walk a little

Answer (score -4):

> How much time do you spend writing tests?

---

> Do you drink coffee?

---

> Do you prefer working remotely?

---

> Which technology do you use in order to keep up to date with technical news.

---

> Do you work outside your work hours?

---

> Do you work on-call?

---

> What do you think about working in an open-plan environment?

Answer (score -4):

**My question:** Do you spend time researching possible valid answers when writing validation (e.g. for a name field on a web form), or just go with what you believe to be correct and wait for someone else to argue it?

**My reason:** Even now in 2018, most online contact/registration forms *still* tell me that my surname is invalid because it has an apostrophe in it (O'L______). I'm sure plenty of other people have this issue and I wonder why it's not more widely addressed within the industry.

Comment: I think this may be moot, since this is technically past the deadline, but I think this would have been better received if you'd asked 'How do you research possible valid answers...' and suggested possible answers including "I don't do research for this task" and "I don't do this task". FWIW, I have a similar problem and I imagine anyone with a very long/short name, hyphenated name, multiple middle names, or no surname does too.

Comment: In hindsight this sounds really passive aggressive haha, it really wasn’t written that way!

Answer (score -5):

Do you prefer interpreted or compiled languages?

I would like to see what current developers are interested. While I understand that we can guess the answer to this question looking at the popular languages , I believe it does not really answer the question.

In my opinion , a lot of people prefer to use interpreted languages such as Python because their syntax is simpler compared to the majority of the compiled languages. In that sense , I would like to see if the interpreted language is what attracts people or if people is more concerned about a language with a simpler syntax.

Answer (score -5):

**How many days of leave do you need in a year?**

Every employee asks how much leave they can get before joining the company.

Comment: Does leaves mean vacation? (Sorry, not a native speaker)

Comment: you can say that.

Comment: Hmm. In my country the amount of vacation is mostly defined by law (5 weeks). I almost never heard that someone negotiated additional days during job search. Afaik, the situation is the same in most central European countries, thus the importance will depend very much on where you are.

Answer (score -6):

Are you a polyglot programmer?

1.Yes

2.No

As a Full Stack Engineer, what are various resource to update your knowledge?

1. Online Course
2. Official Documentations
3. Self-learn from various websites
4. Others. Please specify_______

Answer (score -7):

Perhaps a question to ask which we would know why, "**Why do you choose to become a computer programmer/software developer**"?

Comment: What would be the options? If everybody just writes a freestyle paragraph, there is no way to make that into an digestible chunk of data.

Comment: "or did you choose at all?"

Comment: Nice question to experiment with NLP/ML analysis of the results.

Comment: @nvoigt, well, there could be a lot of options to choose from. To mention a few items, 1. I choose to become a developer because I love to solve challenging problems; 2. Programming is my passion and I can't live without it; 3.  I want to earn big bucks of money and help the poor (maybe not relevant).  We could possibly create an application to randomly generate an options for the user to choose from.

Answer (score -7):

Do you have any mental condition such as Asperger or bipolar?

Comment: While I found this question interesting, I'm pretty sure many people don't know if they have one or the other, so it could be not that relevant.

Comment: I like it, you could add "or feel you have"

Comment: https://www.mentalhealth.com/home/disorders.html I wish everyone was familiar with mental health issues to quickly identify them.

Comment: Im sad to see this question marked down as in fact this was also going to be my suggestion, people often view mental disorders as a disadvantage, it would be interesting to see how many like me are dyslexic and asbergers and how they do at work and how comfortable they are.

Comment: *how they do at work and how comfortable they are* @BugFinder I think if this answer were edited to include follow up questions like that it'd be received better. It's also unclear whether this question is meant to include *all* mental health issues where bipolar and Aspergers are just examples, or do they only mean conditions similar to those two and don't want something like memory issues counted.

Answer (score -7):

How much water do you drink daily?

Reason for this question:

People who drink less water may be performing worse than they are capable of and in the long term it indeed makes them average developers.

Ref: *[Stay Hydrated: People Who Stop Drinking Water Risk Brain Shrinkage, Chronic Diseases](https://www.medicaldaily.com/hydration-dehydration-stay-hydrated-drinking-water-380041)*

Answer (score -7):

Have you experienced passive-aggressive behavior from tech experts trying to "help" you?

In my novice days (and to some extent even today), I often found that answers to my tech support questions were deliberately framed in such a way as to appear "helpful" while serving to increase my frustration by not giving a complete answer. To a confused newbie, it just appears that the expert is trying to demonstrate their superiority and show disdain for the ignorant knowledge seeker in a passive-aggressive fashion. For some reason, this seems to be particularly bad for questions involving Linux.

Answer (score -8):

> What's your favorite band/genre of music to listen to while
>   working/programming, and the favorite snack/drink to keep yourself
>   alert?

This sounds like an interesting piece of information to gather from programmers around the world...

In addition to this, we can also ask about the **favorite type of cheese perhaps?**

Comment: I love cheese. Smoked, aged, Gouda. I go long periods between listening to music (downtempo, nu-jazz, electro-swing, goa-trance, post-rock) and silence.

Comment: @Chloe, wow, thats a long list of music.. I usually prefer gaming music while coding.. It does not divide my attention :)

Comment: LOL. That question will fail, because the US only knows Cheddar, Jack and Blue...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Here, have the French stamp of approval from for that comment!

Answer (score -8):

Taking into account all overtime and from-home work, what is your hourly rate?

What app or website do you use to listen to music?

Open plan or office?

Have you ever experienced sexual harassment?

Have you ever experienced discrimination based on your age, race, or perceived gender?

Answer (score -8):

> Is it important to you what country are you co-workers from?

Or

> Do you prefer co-workers from same country or you'd rather work with
>   people from around the world ?

Answer (score -16):

Topic **Time management**

1. How to become the best programmer with managing personal growth and
   family?
2. How to handle the office team, personal growth, and family with less time?

Comment: This wouldn't work for a survey, because the answers would be freeform and there would be no way to analyze the results.

Comment: Those are not questions. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score -16):

- Do you believe in free will?
- Are you libertarian or socialist?
- Is artificial intelligence a threat or a tool?
- What is your Myers-Briggs personality type?
- What nootropics do you use?
- Do you have anxiety? (General, social, etc.)
- What is your IQ?