# Can we have a question into the next developer survey regarding unit testing?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

There are a lot of people wondering ***How many developers write unit tests?*** I have seen this question and searched it on Google as I meet a lot of developers at conferences lately and I keep wondering how many (if any) tests do they write.

I was only able to find articles like [this](https://blog.hubstaff.com/survey-many-developers-write-unit-tests/) which doesn't offer too much accurate data about it. I think that the data which could be pulled out from the next survey on this topic could be a valuable resource on the Internet these days.

What do you think? Could a question like this be added to the next survey?

Comment: Normaly these kind of requests are posted as an answer, if [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375907/developer-survey-2019-any-topic-suggestions) (by se) appears, which questions we want to see in the next survey.

Answer (score 9):

Anita Taylor from SE's staff has been collecting suggestions for the 2019 Developer Survey [in this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375907/2422776) and has explicitly asked for suggestions to be made by November 2nd, 2018.

According to that, you missed the deadline for this suggestion.
You could, of course, hold on to it and suggest it again for the 2020 Developer Survey.

Comment: I am sorry, it just crossed my mind...

Comment: Forunately, the topic was already suggested in that thread ;-)

Comment: @JessedeBruijne where? Could you leave a link to it, or just the beginning of the answer so I could find it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @meJustAndrew right [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375959/8343610), suggested by Magisch