# Why are there no mentions of GraphQL in the 2019 Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

GraphQL is not listed anywhere as an option in the 2019 Developer Survey—or at least I don't see it.

Why?

I expected to see it under "frameworks" or "databases" as an option in the polls.

Comment: They usually take suggestions ahead of running the poll and I'm guessing noone suggested it. Strictly speaking it isn't really a programming language or a programming environment either,

Comment: Can definitely be in the tools sections, kinda odd for such a hype framework/tool - thus my question here

Comment: I don't see it fitting into any of the current categories, but that's not to say it shouldn't be included in the next one. It would make sense to also include something to compare it with (REST, SOAP, or the very popular "Total Chaos"). I wouldn't mind seeing frameworks like React/Angular/Vue/etc either but I suppose they also have to consider the size of the thing. Try suggesting. I'm sure there'll be a post similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375907/developer-survey-2019-any-topic-suggestions) for the 2020 survey.

Comment: Wow, I've just now learned that GraphQL (I think, "graph query language"), what a nice looking concept!